Looking for the meaning of さらってちゃん
I came across the word さらってちゃん, and Google translated as "kidnapper." Is it correct? Is there another meaning?
Here's the whole paragraph:
さらってちゃんは生まれて初めて自分から襲われようと していた。
Thank you in advance.

No, さらってちゃん does not mean "kidnapper." It refers to someone who wants to be kidnapped.
The most common example of this type of expression is かまってちゃん. The original verb is かまう, meaning "to care about."  When it change to かまってちゃん, it describes someone who wants attention from others.
Similarly, the original verb of さらってちゃん is さらう, meaning "to  kidnap." So さらってちゃん refers to someone who wants to be kidnapped.
It's important to note that 〜てちゃん ends with ちゃん, which is often used with children's names. This adds a nuance of childish behavior. さらってちゃん sounds like a person (probably a girl) pretending to be vulnerable so that the boy she likes can't help but "kidnap" her.
